# How to find the source of Android layouts in Eclipse or documentation

Tags: android

I want find and learn the Android source. For example `android.R.layouts`. Where can I find this source?
I searched in Eclipse via the File Explorer, but I did't find it.

Comment: If I type somewhere into my code `android.R.` and I press the keys `Ctrl` + `space`, then Eclipse suggests some...

Comment: I want see code android source.

Comment: There isn't really any Java source of significance in `android.R.layouts`. It is just a bunch of constant definitions. It will look a lot like your `R` class. What source are you expecting to see?

Comment: single and multiple choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is part of the android library, it is condensed and isnt in the app, its in android itself. You cant read it unless you decompile the android UI.

Comment: Maybe there are another way?

Comment: If there is, I do not know of it. However, Android is much more open-source than other OS's, so maybe there is a decompiled version or an explanation somewhere. To get the acutal class though, I don't think you can. Maybe I'm wrong, if anyone finds a way please correct me.